# how to just get the ID out of the json without []?

Tags: json, discord.py

is there a way to use something diffenrent to just get the ID without the `[]` in the json file, without removing or adding something? only things i know are "append" and "remove" and something like `read`, `get`, `load` or `check` didn't work.  questionmarks are there where i need the right word. If i just type in `f'Name: <@{json_dict["blockedUser"]>'` i just get the ID in the `[]` and `<@` and `>` are just there. i would love to see a solution. if possible, i would display the `user.display_name` instead of the mention in `Name:`. Thanks for the help!

```
    @commands.command(name='checkblock')  # checks if a user is on the list of blocked users
    async def checkblock(self, ctx):
        user = User
        with open('./bot_config/blocked_users.json', 'r') as json_file:
            json_dict = json.load(json_file)
        await ctx.send('Here are the blocked users:\n'
                       f'Name: <@{json_dict["blockedUser"]???(user.id)}>'
                       f'ID: {json_dict["blockedUser"].???(user.id)}')
        return
```

Here is my .json file with an ID inside.

```
{
    "blockedUser": [
        360881524410810380
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of your json file? Otherwise we have to guess at the layout a tad

Comment: i added my json file

Answer (score 1):

`json_dict["blockedUser"]` is a list, so you can loop through it's content:

```py
@commands.command(name='checkblock')  # checks if a user is on the list of blocked users
async def checkblock(self, ctx):
    with open('bot_config/blocked_users.json') as file:
        json_dict = json.load(file)

    template = 'Name: <@{}> (ID: {})'
    member_list = '\n'.join([template.format(id, id) for id in json_dict])
  
    await ctx.send(f'Here are the blocked users:\n{member_list}')
```

If you want the member's display_name, you'll have to get the `discord.Member` object, either with:

- [`discord.Guild.fetch_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_member#discord.Guild.fetch_member)
- [`discord.Guild.get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_member#discord.Guild.get_member)
- [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20utils%20get#discord.utils.get)